# FirebaseDynamicLink: long link working but short link not

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, dynamic-links

I am building an app that has invite links.

Links are working in Android app but in iOS, long link working but short link not.

here's my code in appdelegate to handle dynamic link

```
func handleDynamicLink(_ dynamicLink: DynamicLink?) -> Bool {
        guard let dynamicLink = dynamicLink else { return false }
        guard let deepLink = dynamicLink.url else { return false }
        let queryItems = URLComponents(url: deepLink, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true)?.queryItems
        let invitedBy = queryItems?.filter({(item) in item.name == "invitedby"}).first?.value
        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
        if user != nil
        {
            print("invitedBy:\(invitedBy ?? "nil")")
            //Add to user's team
            UserObject().addTeamMember(userId: invitedBy!, delegate: nil)
            
        }
        else
        {
            self.invitedBy = invitedBy!
        }

     return true
    }




func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
        
        let sourceApplication = options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String?
        print("open url: \(url)")
        if url.absoluteString == "newtask" {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name:NSNotification.Name("newtask"), object: nil)
        }
        if FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()?.handleOpen(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication) ?? false {
            return true
        }
        if DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().shouldHandleDynamicLink(fromCustomSchemeURL: url)
        {
            let dynamicLink = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().dynamicLink(fromCustomSchemeURL: url)
            print("dynamicLink: \(dynamicLink!.url?.absoluteString ?? "nil")")
            return handleDynamicLink(dynamicLink)
        }
        // other URL handling goes here.
        if url.scheme == "homescreen"
        {
            print("NavigateToHomeScreen")
            if let tabbarController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController
            {
                tabbarController.selectedIndex = 0
                let planNavigationController = tabbarController.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController
                planNavigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
            }
            return true
        }
        else if url.scheme == "newtask"
        {
            print("NavigateToNewTask")
            if let tabbarController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController
            {
                tabbarController.selectedIndex = 0
                let planNavigationController = tabbarController.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController
                planNavigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
                planNavigationController.viewControllers[0].performSegue(withIdentifier: "toTask", sender: self)
            }
            return true
        }
        else
        {
            print("url.scheme : \(url.scheme ?? "nil")")
        }
        return false
    }
```

i've add these codes in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
FirebaseOptions.defaultOptions()?.deepLinkURLScheme = Settings.deepLinkURLScheme
FirebaseApp.configure()
```

and in info.plist i've add these

```
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>homescreen</string>
        <string>newtask</string>
        <string>-----.page.link</string>
        <string>https://-----.page.link</string>
        <string>https://-----.me</string>
    </array>
```

When I click the long link it works but shortlink returns nil and i get error like "Dynamic link web URL query item is empty"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added your domain value in **Associated domain** like **"dev.hnb.com"**

[image]

```
// MARK: - Deep Linking

func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
                 restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool 
{
    let myUrl: String? = userActivity.webpageURL?.absoluteString
    print(myUrl)
}
```

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
AASA FILE FOR Verifies
--------------------
    {
      "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
          {
            "appID": "******1738.com.app",
            "components": [
              {
                "/": "/documentationsucksforios13",
                "comment": "This documentation is awful"
              },
              {
              "/": "/customer/account/createpassword/*",
                   "?": { "_query_id": "?*" },
                            "?": { "_query_token": "?*" },
                    "?": { "id": "?*" },
                            "?": { "token": "?*" }              
              },
        {
              "/": "/customer/account/createpassword/*",
                    "?": { "id": "?*" },
                            "?": { "token": "?*" }              
              }
            ],
            "paths": [ "/documentationsucksforios12" ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "webcredentials": {
        "apps": [ "******1738.com.app" ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: i've already did it. dynamiclink works if i copy-paste the link to safari and open the app.

Comment: send some email and please check from that navigate or else send it in skype so you can verify it's working or not Thanks in advance

Comment: hope your AASA FIle is okay

Comment: AASA file is fine. working with long url, not working with short link.